# Qt: Session Management Error

Tags: qt

Recently I changed the hostname of my computer and now every time I start a qt program i get a message that says

_IceTransSocketUNIXConnect: Cannot connect to non-local host [My old hostname]

Qt: Session managment error: Could not open network socket

But the program still works fine. It just is slow to start up. I am using ubuntu 9.04. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you have an old session being saved by your window manager (typically GNOME or KDE) that still references the previous hostname (dev3).

Disposing of that session file might solve your problem. Under KDE these are stored in "`~$USER/.kde/share/config/session/`". There are also directories based upon hostname in `~$USER/.kde/(cache|socket|tmp)-$hostname` which you can delete the old ones for the previous hostname. I'm assuming Linux/BSD platform for directory paths, adjust as necessary for other platform targets.

I'm not sure of GNOME session file placement. `find ~$USER/ -name "*session*"` might be a good start.

Comment: I had the problem even with the same hostname. I removed entire .kde and it fixed it.
Thanks!

Comment: is it safe to remove the entire .kde? I removed the files in "~$USER/.kde/share/config/session/" and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try doing this "unsetenv SESSION_MANAGER"

Comment: Have same issue in Ubuntu/Unity

Comment: Is there really a folder called `~$USER` somewhere, or do you mean just `$HOME` or `~` maybe?

Comment: @hello_fr1end - `~` is the current user's home dir.  `~$USER` is the home dir of `$USER`,  that you can use for example when you are `root` and want to goto a certain user's home dir.

Comment: Is this maybe some special alias or something system specific? When I say `echo ~$USER` on my linux it translates to `~philipp` (which does not exist), while `echo ~` and `echo $HOME` both translate to my correct home directory `/home/philipp`. The command you wrote in your answer: `find ~$USER/ -name "*session*"` gives me `find: '~philipp/': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 12):

In bash you can do

```
export -n SESSION_MANAGER
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer and add references to the (official) documentation if possible.

Comment: Thank you, I am using GNOME with Ubuntu 20.04, and this actually fixed my issue with the network socket.

Though with that said, I would love to know how this command fixed it?

Comment: Just type in a terminal *help export*, it will show (among other things)  *... -n remove the export property from each NAME*.

Comment: It has fixed my issue with running an application with flatpak. However it's not clear why it has worked out, I agree with @m7913d